# Is there a way to filter in Django using the equal magic method?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-filters

Some background just in case there is a better way to do this other than the way I am trying:

I am requesting data of a rest API. When the data is received I want to check if a model containing this data already exists. The rest API does not give an ID for data entry so I cannot use this to see if a model instance already exists.

I have created an equal magic method for the model that checks several of the fields to see if they are equal and returning the appropriate boolean. This works fine when checking for example `if instance == other_instance`.

The issue arises when I try to filter or get to check the DB.
`breach = Breach.objects.get(self=breach1)`

I could check by specifying the fields each time but this would lead to some duplicated code over time and make the code base maintainable.

I am still newish to using Django so apologies if Django has a simple way of doing this.

Comment: There's no ID at all?  Not a numeric or GUID or anything?  Is there something that's unique that perhaps isn't obvious that it's unique?

Comment: No not at all, it is a bit of a head-scratcher of why they haven't included an id of any kind.
The data set isn't too big - around 500 entires. I could just create a method to loop through and check if it is already in the DB but I think this isn't a great solution and won't scale